# Google Assistant / Dialogflow Push Notifcations without Actions API

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Do I need use Firebase Actions API to send push notifications and daily updates for my Google Assistant Bot?  I already have a push notifications service built on a non-google platform that I use to send notifications to my mobile app.

Looking at the documentation and the code posted [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) it is not very obvious if I can do without the Actions API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can push notifications to them via your existing mechanism if you have their account info to push to, if you do not, then you will need to use the Assistant Action API.